# How can't I sort by a number in descending order of course code

Tags: c++, sorting

I am writing a program to manage a list of records. The user first inputs several records, until the string `"END"` that indicates the end of input. Then input a student id and output all record of the student in descending order of course code

I am trying to use a bubble sort to do this, but I don't know why my program is not working. Can you guys give me any hints?? The `change()` function is to change the course code to `int` without `A`.

Sample input

```
SEHH2042 19100001A 76.4
SEHH2042 18001234A 85.2
SEHH2042 19000123A 45.5
SEHH3140 18001234A 89.3
SEHH1034 19100001A 45.7
SEHH1034 18001234A 88.4
SEHH2271 18001234A 85.4
END
18001234A
```

Sample output

```
SEHH3140 89.3
SEHH2271 85.4
SEHH2042 85.2
SEHH1034 88.4
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace::std;

int change(string id) {
    int num;
    string dd(id, 4, 7);
    num = atoi(dd.c_str());
    return num;
}

int main()
{
    string subject[1000], x, tmp1;
    string id[1000], y, search, tmp2;
    double mark[1000], z = 0, sum = 0, tmp3;
    int count = 0, flag = 0, id2[100], p = 0, count2 = 0, tmp4;
    //input
    do {
        cin >> x;
        if (x == "END") {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        cin >> y;
        cin >> z;
        subject[count] = x;
        id[count] = y;
        mark[count] = z;
        p = change(x);
        id2[count] = p;
        count++;
    } while (flag != 1);

    // sort by course code
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        for (int k = count - 1; k > i; k--) {
            if (id2[k] > id2[k - 1]) {
                tmp1 = subject[k];
                tmp2 = id[k];
                tmp3 = mark[k];
                tmp4 = id2[k];
                subject[k] = subject[k - 1];
                id[k] = id[k - 1];
                mark[k] = mark[k - 1];
                id2[k] = id2[k - 1];
                subject[k] = tmp1;
                id[k] = tmp2;
                mark[k] = tmp3;
                id2[k] = tmp4;
            }
        }
    }

    cin >> search;
    // search the result of the student
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (search == id[i]) {
            cout << subject[i] << " " << mark[i] << endl;
            //cout << id2[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to take out your text-book and study the chapters on *structures* (or classes). With a structure (or class) you can collect related data into a single entity, and you could then create an array of this single entity instead of having multiple arrays. It will make your code smaller and simpler.

Comment: Write a *free standing* function that compares two structure instances and returns true if the first instance is greater than the second.  Pass the function to `std::sort`.

Comment: If you want to sort something, why are you not using [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't use parallel arrays.  Your issue is an example of the complexity of using parallel arrays.  Use a collection of structures:

```
struct Student
{
    std::string subject;
    std::string id;
    double mark;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Student& s);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Student& s)
{
    input >> s.subject;
    input >> s.id;
    input >> s.mark;
    input.ignore(1000, '\n'); // ignore to the end of the line.
    return input;
}

std::vector<Student> database;
Student s;
std::string text_line;
while (std::getline(cin, text_line))
{
    if (text_line == "END")
    {
        break;
    }
    std::istringstream text_stream(text_line);
    text_line >> s;
    database.push_back(s);
}
```

The above code reads in a record as a structure and appends to the database.

Here's a function to order by subject:

```
bool Order_By_Subject(const Student& a, const Student& b)
{
    return a.subject < b.subject;
}
```

The sorting by subject is as simple as:

```
std::sort(database.begin(), database.end(), Order_By_Subject);
```

Sorting by other fields (members) can be accomplished by writing addition ordering functions and supplying to `std::sort` like the above example.

This is a lot simpler than using multiple arrays.

**Edit 1: Changing sort order**
Ordering descending by subject can be accomplished by changing the comparision statement:

```
bool Order_Descending_By_Subject(const Student& a, const Student& b)
{
    return a.subject > b.subject;
}
```

Then calling the sort function:

```
std::sort(database.begin(), database.end(), Order_Descending_By_Subject);
```